# How to use jQuery promise with element animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

How can I invoke a callback after 2 animations completed? The animations should happen at the same time, but after both are complete a callback should run.

I have this so far:

```
$element1.animate({top: element2_pos}, 200);
$element2.animate({top: element1_pos}, 200, function(){ /* callback code */ });
```

How do I combine that with a promise or deferred object? Is there a smart way to join both animations?

Comment: If both animations take 200ms to complete then your code should work as it is

Comment: `$.when($element1.animate(...).promise(), $element2.animate(...).promise()/*, ...*/).done(function() { ... })`

Comment: @Andreas Please make that an answer. Btw, I think you don't even need to call `.promise()` yourself, `$.when` will do it for you

Comment: @Bergi Why using `$.when()` there? What is the benefit? I really don't get it?!

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't sure, but yes. `.promise()` isn't needed: https://jsfiddle.net/xvnLj9ct/

Comment: @Andreas Well, it combines multiple promises from multiple elements. Your answer, just putting all elements in a single collection and calling `.promise()` on that does work as well (I wasn't sure whether it might just wait for the event queue of the first element, but it does await all of them indeed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

*Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.*

---

```js
var animDiv1 = $("div.div1").animate({ left: 200 }, 1000),
  animDiv2 = $("div.div2").animate({ left: 200 }, 2000);

$.when(animDiv1, animDiv2).done(function() {
  console.log("done");
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red
}
.div1 { top: 0 }
.div2 { top: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It just like calling it:

```
$element1.add($element2).promise().done(function(){
  //callback when all animations are done
});
```

```js
var $element1 = $('div.first');
var $element2 = $('div.second');

$element1.animate({
  top: $element2.position().top
}, 200);
$element2.animate({
  top: $element1.position().top
}, 200, function() { /* callback code */ });

$element1.add($element2).promise().done(function() {
  console.log('callback when all animations are done');
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
div.second {
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  DIV1
</div>
<div class="second">
  DIV2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can invoke a callback after 2 animations are completed

```
function doAnimation(callback) {
    var i = 0;
    var progress = function () {
        i++;
        if (2 == i) {
            callback && callback();
        }
    };
    $element1.animate({ top: element2_pos }, 200, progress);
    $element2.animate({ top: element1_pos }, 200, progress);
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated?

Comment: you want to invoke a callback, not to return a promise. so using promise here is a overkill unless you want to return a promise.

Comment: Promises are made to simplify exactly the callback code you created. That should be enough reason to use them, wouldn't it? And yes, returning a promise is more reasonable than taking a `callback` parameter.